# a href link is showing up in Firefox but not in IE

Tags: internet-explorer, hyperlink

So I have a javascript carousel and I needed to add a link below the code, it shows up fine in Firefox, Safari and Chrome but the link does not show up in IE 7. I have tried adjusting different elements of the CSS but nothing is really working. Can anyone help me adjust the CSS accordingly to show this link? Its the 50th Anniversary link, here is the live page: www.luc.edu/rome

***Edit:

Ok after a little bit more re-coding, when I changed the div reference around the a href to "display: absolute" it showed up, so I had to apply the IE CSS only element, so "*display:absolute" so it did not effect the other browsers that actually work.

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest to generate a conitional-css. http://www.quirksmode.org/css/condcom.html
You can create workarrounds for old legacy IE in that file without affecting other browser.

Comment: It is difficult to do that because that template is applied to numerous other sites but that particular CSS tag is only called on that site, so I can only change the css accordingly because changing the template will effect other sites.